# Display Random Number by Javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I'm following:

```
window.onload = generateRandomNumber;
function generateRandomNumber(){
var n = 25;
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = number;
}
```

Now I want to show a random number that from 20 to 25. How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: `minimum + Math.random() * (maximum - minimum)`

Answer (score 2):

Just try:

```
var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*5) + 1;
n += 20;
```

The `n` value will be between 20 and 25...